# Using the DirectX 11 SDK, How do I load a video (with sound) and play it?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, directx, directx-11

I am having problems locating any documentation or examples for rendering video on a form using DirectX. I need to use DirectX because I will be putting overlay's on the video loaded dynamically. I will also want to perform transitions between 2 video instances.

I can not find any documentation on Google or Microsoft's site, any thing to point me in the right direction would help. Such as render the video on a 3d object as a texture, maybe... IDK?

This is for Visual Studio 2010, .net framework 4.0, using vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectX 11 is not for rendering video.  It is for 3D graphics, Audio and Input.

Look up [DirectShow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectShow) (Which MS are trying to replace) or the [Media Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Foundation) (which they are attempting to replace DShow with).

Comment: I found a solution, and its really bizarre how easy it is. I'm using the WPF media elements. The Media Elements, provided a computer has enough resources, can be used underneath content as well as transparent over another media element. Now I'll I need is to add live video feeds to the mix and all my problems are resolved.

Comment: I'll look into the Media Foundation, as it might be a better approach.